# How to display row and column numbers in a better way

Tags: javascript

I would like to show row and column numbers in a format of `(x, y)`. I do an `if` check for each `row` variable. I was wondering if there would be a better approach to show row and column numbers.

There are 3 rows. The 1st row has 2 columns, the 2nd row has 1 column, and the 3rd row has 3 columns. 2nd and 3rd rows may not exist at all, but the 1st row always exists.

All I did was to run a loop iteration for `rowFirst`, `rowSecond`, and `rowThird`. Is my approach fine or could it be better?

```js
const labels = [];
const rows = 3;
/////////////
const rowFirst = 2;
const rowSecond = 1; // could be ''.
const rowThird = 3; // could be ''.
/////////////

for (let i = 0; i < rowFirst; i += 1) {
  labels.push(`(1, ${i + 1})`);
}

if (rowSecond) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rowSecond; i += 1) {
    labels.push(`(2, ${i + 1})`);
  }
}

if (rowThird) {
  for (let i = 0; i < rowThird; i += 1) {
    labels.push(`(3, ${i + 1})`);
  }
}

console.log('LABELS', labels);
```

Comment: I also have a variable to define the number of rows `rows`, but I couldn't figure out how l could use it with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you can use a two-dimensional array to define the number of rows and columns

Comment: Could you please provide a pseudo code for me to understand the logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is a two dimensional array solution:

```
const labels = [];
const rows = [2, 1, 3];

for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
  for (let j = 0; j < rows[i]; j += 1) {
    labels.push(`(${i + 1}, ${j + 1})`)
  }
}

console.log('LABELS', labels); // LABELS [ '(1, 1)', '(1, 2)', '(2, 1)', '(3, 1)', '(3, 2)', '(3, 3)' ]
```

If your variables are unchangeable you could do this:

```
const labels = [];
const rows = 3;
/////////////
const rowFirst = 2;
const rowSecond = 1; // could be ''.
const rowThird = 3; // could be ''.
/////////////

const rowsArray = [rowFirst, rowSecond, rowThird];

for (let i = 0; i < rowsArray.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < rowsArray[i]; j++) {
    labels.push(`(${i + 1}, ${j + 1})`)
  }
}

console.log('LABELS', labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

I added some comments with examples to understand the process.

```js
const labels = [];

// Total rows should be
const total_rows = 3;

/** 
* Total columns should be in each row. For example-
* In row one (index 0) = 2 column
* In row two (index 1) = 1 column
* In row three (index 2) = 3 column
* So, we can write it like below-
*/

const total_columns = [2, 1, 3]

/** 
* r = row
* c = column
* Outer loop = To create total number of rows
* Inner Loop = To create total number of columns defined in each row.
* Means if r = 0 (first row), then total_columns in row 1 would be =
* total_columns[0] = 2
*/

for(let r=0; r < total_rows; r++) {
 for(let c=0; c < total_columns[r]; c++) {
  labels.push(`row-${r+1}, column-${c+1}`)
 }
}


console.log('LABELS', labels);
```